# Custom Wide Tile in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I currently have the code below that creates a custom layout for the Tile. It only resizes to the small and medium and not the wide.

I need to update the code to support the wide tile of Windows Phone 8, but I need to be able to customise where the text appears.

The code uses a template where I can change the background of the tile and the position of the text.

Any ideas on how I can make this go into a wide tile? And also to be able to out in multiple lines of text.

```
  ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(busStopName.Text));


            TileControl frontTile = new TileControl();
            TileName = "";
            TileName = busStopName.Text;
            TileData tileData = new TileData() {Text1 = busStopName.Text };
            frontTile.DataContext = tileData;

            frontTile.Measure(new Size(173, 173));
            frontTile.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 173, 173));
            var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
            bmp.Render(frontTile, null);
            bmp.Invalidate();

            var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            var filename = "/Shared/ShellContent/" + busStopName.Text + ".jpg";

            using (var stream = isf.OpenFile(filename, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, 173, 173, 0, 100);
            }

            var data = new StandardTileData
            {
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + busStopName.Text + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute)
            };

            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/LiveTimes.xaml?name=" + busStopName.Text, UriKind.Relative), data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ShellTile has additional overload for create that allows optional Boolean argument specifying whether wide tile is supported or not. You need to use that to support wide tile.

have a look at my blogpost
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/fliptile-cycletile-and-various-iterations-of-wpdev-sdks/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207919(v=vs.105).aspx

Btw you need to use one of the new tile templates like FlipTileData and pass that. StandardTileData cannot support wide and is inherited from #wp7.5

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971(v=vs.105).aspx

```
FlipTileData TileData = new FlipTileData()
{
   Title = "[title]",
   BackTitle = "[back of Tile title]",
   BackContent = "[back of medium Tile size content]",
   WideBackContent = "[back of wide Tile size content]",
   Count = [count],
   SmallBackgroundImage = [small Tile size URI],
   BackgroundImage = [front of medium Tile size URI],
   BackBackgroundImage = [back of medium Tile size URI],
   WideBackgroundImage = [front of wide Tile size URI],
   WideBackBackgroundImage = [back of wide Tile size URI],
};

ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/LiveTimes.xaml?name=" + busStopName.Text, UriKind.Relative), TileData, true);
```

Comment: Ok, so  I have alterit it like so 'ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/LiveTimes.xaml?name=" + busStopName.Text, UriKind.Relative), data, supportsWideTile = true);' but it throws an error when I try it.